# Partial derivative of special function

Tags: partial-derivative

How can I get the derivative of the following formula with respect to X?

$$ g = \frac{X\exp({Y' X)} Z (Z)^{\exp{(Y'X)}}}{1-Z^{\exp{(Y'X)}}}$$

where X is a vector of unknown parameters and Y is a vector same length as X but known, such that for example if the length of parametr X is 2, we have $$X_1 *Y_1+X_2*Y_2+X_3*Y_3$$ Also Z is a vector which is known.

Comment: Do you need to compute $\frac{\partial g_j}{\partial x_i}$, where $X=(x_1,...,x_i,...,x_n)$ and $j\in 1,\cdots,n$?

Comment: How would you define $Xexp(Y'X)Z$? In the middle you have a scalar ($exp(Y'X)$), but both $X$ and $Z$ are vectors.